# Issue with send_keys python selenium

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

I'm trying to make a little Facebook group auto post script using python and selenium

First of all I'm uploading 3/4 photos using the following code:

```
l = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('input')
for g in l:
    print(g)
    try:
        if g == driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']"):
            print("Found")
            logging.debug("Found input for image uploading")
            g.send_keys(
                '/var/www/html/v1/insta-post/AutoPostFB/images/0.jpg \n/var/www/html/v1/insta-post/AutoPostFB/images/1.jpg \n/var/www/html/v1/insta-post/AutoPostFB/images/2.jpg')
            print("File/s Uploaded")
            logging.debug("Images uploaded")
            time.sleep(5)
            # break
    except:
        print("Element not found after upload")
        logging.debug("Element for upload not found")
```

Then I push the post text, since the textbox is already on focus

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(info)
actions.perform()
time.sleep(1)
```

The issue is that every space in the info variable is abnormally converted into a return key

so if the text is like

```
info = "HEI HOW'S IS GOING?"
```

what I get in the textbox is

```
IS
GOING
HEY
HOW'S
```

Someone can help me out? I've tried like everything

Comment: Without seeing the `info` variable, we can't really help...

Comment: please add the screen shot of the text box and full code flow

Comment: If the problem is with a textbox, what is the relevance of the file upload code?

Comment: Do file input boxes typically take multiple new lines?

Comment: @JohnGordon I've written that the info variable is the following
info = "HEI HOW'S IS GOING?"